# Targeting of Control Water spell when used to slow water elementals

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, spells, targeting

In both [Pathfinder](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/controlWater.html) and [3.5](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/controlWater.htm) (pretty much exact wording for both), the Control Water spell has an intriguing effect under the "Lower Water" option of the spell:

> When cast on water elementals and other water-based creatures, this spell acts as a slow spell (Will negates). The spell has no effect on other creatures.

If a wizard chose this option when casting the spell, how would this be accomplished in regards to targeting and area of effect? Control Water's main listing shows an *Area*.  The Slow spell's main listing shows *Targets*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When cast on [water elementals](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-water/), [control water](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/control-water/)'s **effect** is the same effect as the [slow](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/slow/) spell:

> An affected creature moves and attacks at a drastically slowed rate. Creatures affected by this spell are staggered and can take only a single move action or standard action each turn, but not both (nor may it take full-round actions). Additionally, it takes a -1 penalty on attack rolls, AC, and Reflex saves. A slowed creature moves at half its normal speed (round down to the next 5-foot increment), which affects the creature’s jumping distance as normal for decreased speed.

But other parts of the spell are unchanged.

You don't have to worry about changing the spell level, casting time, components, duration, target or even saving throw of the *slow* spell, as those are already defined by the *control water* spell, you are simply copying the effects of slow.

This means that the spell **range** is still *long* and not short, the **duration** is *10 minutes/level* and not 1 round/level, the spell now allows a will **saving throw** to negate the effect, and so on.

In other words, the spell block would be something like this *specifically* against [water elementals](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-water/) (i bolded the parts that are treated differently):

> **Control Water (vs water elementals)**
>
> School transmutation [water]; Level cleric/oracle 4, druid 4, shaman 4, sorcerer/wizard 6; Domain water 4; Bloodline aquatic 5
>
> Casting Time 1 standard action
>
> Components V, S, M/DF (a pinch of dust for lower water or a drop of water for raise water
>
> Range long (400 ft. + 40 ft./level)
>
> Area water in a volume of 10 ft./level by 10 ft./level by 2 ft./level (S) **and all water elementals and water-based creatures within that area**
>
> Duration 10 min./level (D)
>
> Saving **Will negates**; Spell Resistance no
>
> **Effect**: An affected creature moves and attacks at a drastically slowed rate. Creatures affected by this spell are staggered and can take only a single move action or standard action each turn, but not both (nor may it take full-round actions). Additionally, it takes a -1 penalty on attack rolls, AC, and Reflex saves. A slowed creature moves at half its normal speed (round down to the next 5-foot increment), which affects the creature’s jumping distance as normal for decreased speed.
>
> Multiple slow effects don’t stack. Slow counters and dispels haste.

Comment: Thank you, ShadowKras.  That's phenomenal detail. And it pretty much answers all the subcomponents of this spell's original issues.